# Microsoft Edge, media query doesn't work correctly

Tags: css, google-chrome, media-queries, microsoft-edge

I tested this media query successfully on Google Chrome but somehow Microsoft Edge has issues with it. Is something wrong with these queries? Or is it just a bug in Microsoft Edge?

**UPDATE:** 
It looks like Edge needs a Class without Media Query, so I added `.height-fix{height:650px}` and it works.

```
@media all and (min-width:875px) and (max-width:980px) { 
.height-fix { 
  height : 610px; 
  } 
} 

@media all and (min-width:768px) and (max-width:875px) { 
.height-fix { 
  height : 575px; 
  } 
} 

@media (max-height:768px) and (min-width:1366px) and (max-width:1366px) { 
.height-fix { 
  height : 520px !important ; 
  } 
}
```

This is the media query that doesn't work it should target devices with a `height` *OVER* 768px and a `width` *OVER* 1367px:

```
@media (min-height:768px) and (min-width:1367px) { 
.height-fix { 
  height : 650px; //this line doesn't apply
  } 
}
```

Comment: Not an answer, but Microsoft's IE (the predecessor of Edge) was always notorious for having CSS support problems when the other major browsers all worked.  I wouldn't be the least surprised if Edge followed this tradition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like Microsoft Edge has an issue with media queries if there the class has no *fallback*

This means that if a css class is only specified inside a media query it sometimes won't work correctly.

So if the CSS looks like this:

```
@media (max-width(123px){
.height-fix {
  height: 650px
  }
}
```

it wont work.
It should to look like this:

```
.height-fix{
height: 100px
}

@media (max-width(123px){
.height-fix {
  height: 650px
  }
}
```