# CSS media query do not work on Microsoft Edge

Tags: javascript, css

```
 @media (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1140px) 
{
  .mr-1024-none
  {
        margin-right: 0px !important;
  }

  .mt-1024
  {
        margin-top: 1rem !important;
  }  

   .d-1024-none 
   {
        display: none !important;   
   }

}
```

I have used the above code for solving issue on ie and edge. The above media query works fine on ie but doesnot work on edge.
After searching enough i found that edge does not support media query.
Can someone help me out!!!

Comment: Edge supports media queries just fine that is not the problem. Without more information we can only quess what might be wrong. Can you post [mcve] that is not working as you intend on Edge?

Comment: "edge does not support media query."...what was your source for this info? https://caniuse.com/#search=media suggests it does. Seriously why would a modern browser not support something which was in common use years before it was even built? You really think that's very likely? Certainly there could be bugs though...for instance maybe your scenario is similar to this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46131245/microsoft-edge-media-query-doesnt-work ?

Comment: Actually my classes which are written inside the query are getting overridden by bootstrap classes. Is there any way to handle it with css only. With Js it is possible.

Comment: @Deepak007 you're CSS is !important. why do you think bootstrap overrides this

Answer (score 0):

As you're using bootstrap, are you sure you're calling your custom stylesheet after Bootstrap call ?
If not, bootstrap rules will take over your custom stylesheet.

Comment: It would actually be useful to see the order & list of CSS files, or inlined stylesheets.

Answer (score 0):

I had quite same problem. If under your min-width the style is the same as between min-width and max-width, remove min-width and it will work. And yes, you have be sure you're calling your custom stylesheet after Bootstrap.

@media screen and (max-width: 1140px) {...}